# Program that Matches Two Sequences of RNA and prints out length of Matching Base Pairs

Tags: python, string, list

I'm having some trouble with a program in which you input two RNA sequences, and prints out the length of the matching base pairs.

Here's what I have so far:

```
def main():

    Sequence1 = ""
    Sequence2 = ""
    print("MatchSequences(Sequence1,Sequence2)")
    MatchSequence = input("Enter the subsequences with each base in single quotes and the subsequences separated a comma")
    input = (x,y)
    x = ([])
    y = ([])
    for i in range(0,len(Sequence1)):
        if x == A

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like:

```
from string import join

def main():
    pairs = {'G':'C', 'C':'G', 'A':'U', 'U':'A'}
    print("MatchSequences(Sequence1, Sequence2)")
    x, y = input("Enter the subsequences with each base in single quotes and the subsequences separated a comma")
    matched = join([a  if pairs[a]==b else '-' for (a, b) in zip(x, y)], sep='')

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Ok, but A and U need to match, as well as G and C.